# csrftoken tag not working after upgrade to Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

I have inherited a Django app that I initially got working on Django 1.9. Recently I have migrated it to Django 1.11 and Python 3.4 (from 2.7). Since then, some admin view that I have has started failing with a 403 Forbidden error, CSRF verification failed. I looked at [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/), and checked the following things:

1. I'm still using `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, but `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` is included in my configuration (it's second, after `SessionMiddleware` and `CommonMiddleware`).
2. The template used includes the `{% csrf_token %}` stuff.
3. The view uses `render_to_response()`, and passes `RequestContext(request)` as the third argument to it.

(None of these changed during or after the Django/Python upgrades, as far as I know.)

I'm not that experienced with Django, although I have quite a bit of Python web programming experience. What am I missing/how could I debug further?

Comment: Total shots in dark: if you look at the source page, do you see the CRSF token?  Are you seeing this when using the django runserver (i.e. manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000)

Comment: No, don't see the CSRF token in the page source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `context_instance` parameter was [deprecated in 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#dictionary-and-context-instance-arguments-of-rendering-functions) and was subsequently removed in 1.10. If you need the request in the context, use [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) instead and pass the request as the first argument. You should pass the context as a plain dictionary in the third parameter.

Comment: Right on the money. Thanks!

Comment: One more question: another view I have passes a second argument to `RequestContext`, `{'form': form}`. What's the best way to do that in the new situation? It's not really clear from the deprecation notice or the docs.

Comment: @djc The dictionary would now be the third argument to `render()`.